# How to resolve error getting while installing paramiko on window system?

Tags: python, pip, paramiko

I have python 2.7.9 installed and have pip already installed. Now, when i try to install paramiko using :

```
 pip install paramiko
```

i get error as :

```
Could not find the version that satisfies the requirement paramiko
No matching distribution found for paramiko.
```

I have pycrypto already installed. So, suggest me how do i install paramiko package.
Also, i have paramiko package copied and when i try to run setup.py i get warnings. So, please suggest how do i install paramiko on my window system.

Comment: Paramiko used key systems. Did you test pycrypto ?

Comment: @SDilmac i have installed pycrypto.

Comment: import sys; print (sys.path) output ?

Comment: ***OR*** sys.path.append("where_your_paramiko") befor import paramiko

Answer (score 0):

Did you try pip upgrade?

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score -2):

These days I just use the [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) compilation by Continuum, which comes with many packages in a single installer (one of which is Paramiko).

Prior to Anaconda, I encountered the same problems as you.  I think I got around this by just dropping the paramiko script in the site-packages folder with the other installed packages.  That was a kluge, but it worked.  That being said, you will not regret going to Anaconda.

Comment: I regret Anaconda. It broke HomeAssistant.